What is the book/author about preserved heads/brains?
Many years ago, I read a sci-fi book about preserving "heads" of people--i.e. their brains and knowledge. One "head" I recall in particular was of a Mississippi riverboat Captain (the head was preserved in fluid in a jar with tubes attached to keep it "alive"). The "head" was an expert in navigating the river, and continued to do so in its preserved state, giving orders and directing the ship. Does anybody recall the name and author?

In roughly which year did you read this? And do you recall anything about the cover?

I think this is Wyrms by Orson Scott Card.
It's set on a distant future planet where preserving heads is commonplace. The river is called The Cranwater, not the Mississippi.

"I'm captain of the ship," said Patience.
"Not any ship I'll sail on, nor any sane person neither," said Sken. "You've got the money, that makes you owner. I've got the know-how, and that makes me captain."
"Supreme authority?"
"Not quite."
"Oh? Who's higher than the captain?"
It wasn't Sken who answered. The voice came from Patience's other side, and it belonged to a man. "Pilot!" he said.
Patience turned-and saw no one, just a monkey jumping up and down as it pumped at a bellows. The bellows was connected to a tube that ran down into a thick glass jar, then up into the windpipe of a head whose eyes just peered over the top.
"Pilot?" asked Patience.
Sken had not yet turned. "Yes, a pilot. Someone who knows the river. Every river is different, and different from year to year, as well." Then she saw the one who had spoken, the head perched in a thick glass jar. Sken wrinkled up her face. "A dead one," she said. "Lot of good he'll do."
"Been up and down Cranwater every one of the last two hundred years," said the head.
"Heads don't learn," said Patience. "Heads don't pay attention, and they forget too quickly."
The monkey kept jumping up and down. It was distracting.
"I pay attention," said the pilot's head. "I know this river. Some pilots, the river's like an enemy, they wrestle it up and down. Some, it's like a god, they worship, they pray, they curse. Some, it's a whore for them, they think they're in charge but she plays them for fools.
Some, it's a lover, a wife, a family, they live and die for it. But me-"
"Come along, young sir," said Sken. But Patience stayed to listen.
"For me, the Cranwater's not like anything else. This river is myself. That's my name, River, as God gave it to me that's my name, the stream is my body, my arms, my legs."

